# How to implement Crystal Reports in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, crystal-reports

I have a Java EE web application. I would like to use reporting in my application, but I don't know to how to use Crystal Reports in Java EE.

I just want to know whether the Crystal Reports Software is required when creating reports in a Java EE web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports is very crude in a Java EE application.  I'm not sure they even actively support their Java libraries anymore.  In any case, here is how we got CR to work (but we are now moving away, replacing with **PDFBox** with PDF fields).

In your `web.xml`, put something like the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_image_uri</param-name>
    <param-value>/crystalreportviewers</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</param-name>
    <param-value>webapp</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
    <description>database reference factory for crystal report</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyCrRef</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Put the `crystalreportsviewers` and `Java_CRJ12_Web_View` folders in your web root.
Add the `crystal-tags-reportviewer.tld` in the `WEB-INF` directory.
Put all of your reports in `WEB-INF/classes`.

You can reuse their `CRHelper.java` class with much changes.

Add the following `CRConfig.xml` in the the WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<CrystalReportEngine-configuration>
    <reportlocation>../..</reportlocation>
    <timeout>0</timeout>
    <ExternalFunctionLibraryClassNames>
        <classname></classname>
    </ExternalFunctionLibraryClassNames>
</CrystalReportEngine-configuration>
```

Include jars in your project/build:

```
com.azalea.ufl.barcode.1.0.jar
CrystalCommon2.jar
CrystalReportsRuntime.jar
cvom.jar
DatabaseConnectors.jar
derby.jar (if using debry)
icu4j.jar
jai_imageio.jar
JDBInterface.jar
jrcerom.jar
keycodeDecoder.jar
log4j.jar
logging.jar
msbase.jar
mssqlserver.jar
msutil.jar
pfjgraphics.jar
QueryBuilder.jar
webreporting-jsf.jar
webreporting.jar
xpp3.jar
Xtreme.jar
```

That's the basic setup.  Now, you'll have to write your report code, and they do have example of that.  I just don't have links readily available.

Comment: thanks, but   if you can tell me how i can get the dependencies  of Include jars for the maven project

Comment: I don't know if the jars are available in maven.  You may have to download them from their website.  Try these two links to get you started: http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports-eclipse/index.html and http://www.javathinking.com/2011/09/using-crystal-reports-java-api-to.html

Comment: hey it's work but i want to get the data from database please can you tell me how to set location of database and refrech report data   my database is ms access